# compare two dictionary key value

Tags: vb.net

I have two dictionary objects one both of type `Dictionary(of Integer, string)`.

I  need to check if the key value in the first dictionary i.e. dc1 is repeated in dictionary dc2 if  so get the key of the repeated key value.
 **The code below works but is there a much better way to do the comparison**

```
    Dim dc1 As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Dim dc2 As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    dc1.Add(1, "student1")
    dc1.Add(2, "student2")
    dc1.Add(3, "student3")
    dc1.Add(4, "student4")
    dc2.Add(1, "student1")
    dc2.Add(2, "student4")
    dc2.Add(3, "student2")
    dc2.Add(4, "student3")
    dc2.Add(10, "student1")
    dc2.Add(11, "student4")

    Dim lstcount1 As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    For Each kvp1 As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String) In dc1
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For Each kvp2 As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String) In dc2
            If kvp1.Value = kvp2.Value Then
                count = count + 1
                If (count > 1) Then

                    lstcount1.Add(kvp2.Key)
                End If


            End If
        Next

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is "better", anyway it is different :

```
Dim dups = dc2.GroupBy(Function(a) a.Value, Function(a) a.Key) _
    .Where(Function(b) b.Count = 2) _
    .ToDictionary(Function(c) c.Key, Function(c) c(1))

For Each kvp1 In dc1
    If dups.ContainsKey(kvp1.Value) Then lstcount1.Add(dups(kvp1.Value))
Next
```

*GroupBy* groups dc2 keys by student names. *Where* filters the groups containing duplicates (2 keys). And *ToDictionary* converts the results to a Dictionary of [duplicated student name, key of the duplicated student name].